# How to make jqgrid row as a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, jqgrid

I am creating one jqgrid and now I want to make its rows as a hyperlink.
So whenever I click on the row it takes all row data and display it in another page???
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

indise your grid definition add this option

```
.... (jqgrid initilization code)

onClickRow: function(ids){
    if (ids != null) {
        var data = $("#list").getRowData(ids);
        location.href = ‘link where you want to go/id=’+ data.UserId;
    }
},

.... (remaining initilization code )
```